# Apply Triggeres to progress openedge database

Tags: java, triggers, openedge

I have done a progress openedge db installation and restore a backup from existing DB. When I run the application I got to know that some triggers are not there in my new database.

I have found some triggeres sql in my original database adn now I want to execute them in my new db environment.

There are around 50 triggers and all are in .sql format. Also those are java triggers.

could some one guide me how to execute those triggers in my new db

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLSCHEMA utility with original database to dump all the triggers.

Example:

```
sqlschema -u dbauser -a oesqldba -T %.% progress:T:localhost:8165:testdb -o mytriggers
```

This will create a file mytriggers.dfsql which contains all your trigger definitions. Use this file to create triggers (just a copy paste in SQLExplorer) in your database and use them.

Comment: Hi Austing Thank you for the reply. I used sqlexp command to run run triggeres one by one and it says now triggeres are already available. But when I try to insert some data into my user table tis give me rror based on this link http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P132226 . But in that resolution says "Recompile all the JAVA SQL triggers and JAVA stored procedures with the JAVA version on the running database server." but I don't know how to do this. Could you advice me please.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no straightforward way to recompile :(

Once way I could think of is, drop all the triggers/stored procedures and recreate them in the new database.

Comment: Thanks Austin, But I have no idea to how to drop the triggers. I'm new to openedge. Could you assist me on this.

Comment: Also do you have idea how do we checked the java version that triggeres compiled.

Comment: Can't you check by looking at the system the backup was  taken on?